# Display Model state Errors in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core, error-handling

How can I display `ModelState` in my View? I have the following code for validation but I am not able to display Modelstate error in my View.

I have this conditions my action:

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(error => error.ErrorMessage));

     else if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {         
            if (updatedProduct.ProductSRDate.Value > DateTime.Now)
                ModelState.AddModelError("ProductSRDate", " Date must be current date or in the past.");               
            var PrjEditMode = await ProductService.GetProductsbyId(id);
            var editMode = Mapper.Map<ProductDetails>(PrjEditMode);
            return View(editMode);
        }
```

In View I have Validation Summary as:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

But it only display `Date must be current date or in the past.` when there is a nullable field it display `Date must be current date or in the past.

`0   "The value '' is invalid."`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Access ModelState class in view with the key :

Controller : `ModelState.AddModelError("ProductSRDate", "Date must be current date or in the past.");`

View : `@Html.ValidationMessage("ProductSRDate")`

But you're code logical error because you add an error to your `ModelState` if `IsValid`.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid || updatedProduct.ProductSRDate.Value > DateTime.Now)
{
    if (updatedProduct.ProductSRDate.Value > DateTime.Now)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ProductSRDate", " Date must be current date or in the past.");
    }
    //return BadRequest(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(error => error.ErrorMessage));
    return View(editMode); // You should return a view and handle Invalid ModelState in view.
}
else
{
    var PrjEditMode = await ProductService.GetProductsbyId(id);
    var editMode = Mapper.Map<ProductDetails>(PrjEditMode);
    return View(editMode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you now i get all messages together but it doesnt show in a view  instead it show json message in a new window as `0 "Date must be current date or in the past."`

Comment: Your request is not clear, sorry. What do you need from the code ? Show the ModelState errors in json ?

Comment: It works but  doesn't display in a view I added this @Html.ValidationMessage("ProductSRDate") but it show as a json format let me add a screenshot of it

Comment: I added the screenshot, can you take a look at it? Thanks

Comment: I also tried these two ` @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) and  <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>`

Comment: I will check it asap

Comment: my bad it word, i forgot to return the view, thank you so much